# Problems understanding LINQ syntax. returned error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am working on an application that accepts a document as an upload, an excel sheet with multiple values. It is breaking and not uploading... I have located where it is breaking but I am having problems understanding this exact LINQ syntax.

```
    public static List<PoolManager> getPoolManagersLoadedinMaster()
    {
        using (HRCMSEntities context = new HRCMSEntities())
        {

            HRCompInfo compInfo = new HRCompInfo();
            DataTable dtCurrYear = compInfo.getConfiguration("CurrentYear");
            var currYear = Convert.ToInt32(dtCurrYear.Rows[0]["Config_Val"].ToString());

            var planningManagerQuery =
            from COMP_REC_ENC in context.COMP_REC_ENC.Where(m => m.Year == currYear)
            select new PoolManager
            {
                Planning_manager_ID = COMP_REC_ENC.Planning_Manager_ID
            };

            var planningManagerList = planningManagerQuery.Distinct().ToList();

            return planningManagerList;
        }
    }
```

This code is breaking when it tries to run

```
PlanningMangerList = planningManagerQuery.Distinct().ToList()
```

I checked the table and the data is there. Can someone help me decipher why this code is breaking on that exact part? Theories would work just fine... I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Special_6'. Invalid column name 'Special_9_New'. Invalid column name 'Special_10_New'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
```

I did reciently change this project from a SIT database to a DEV database... When it comes to entity framework I did update the connection string catalog but am unsure if the connectionString is a problem when it comes to entity framekwork. I updated it to this.

```
<add name="HRCMSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add a catch clause and show us the exception.ToString() output?

Comment: Yes I am doing it now... one moment

Comment: @noobprogrammer - Take another look.

Comment: @JeffreyPadgett - Can we please see the class definition for `PoolManager`?

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Special_6'. Invalid column name 'Special_9_New'. Invalid column name 'Special_10_New'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

Comment: pool manager class definition public class PoolManager
    {
        public string Planning_manager_ID { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @HirasawaYui I updated it for you.

Comment: How about you enable logging of sql queries and then try to execute the query manually to see what's the issue

Comment: OK. That sounds great. Thank you. I wish I could give you an upvote. actually. You helping me just take the exception from a message to converting it to a string helped. if you put it as an officlal answer I will upvote it.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I think it has to do with my entity framework not using the correct connection string. So the code is not correctly executed so when queries are performed using Context.COMP_REC_ENC I am getting broken results.But I found it by converting the exception message from a message to just viewing the exception as a whole. Thanks!!! @ Hirasawa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your error has nothing to do with `Distinct()`, nor with `ToList()`. The error is reported here, because this is the moment that the query that you defined is executed.

I think the problem is in the Select, this looks a bit weird to me.

You have to debug to find out if the problem is in the dbContext, the `Where` or the `Select`.

Add some intermediate test code, every time execute the query.

```
var a = context.COMP_REC_ENC.ToList();
var b = context.COMP_REC_ENC
        .Where(m => m.Year == currYear)
        .ToList();
var c = context.COMP_REC_ENC
        .Where(m => m.Year == currYear)
        .Select(m => new PoolManager
        {
            Planning_manager_ID = COMP_REC_ENC.Planning_Manager_ID
        })
        .ToList();
```

In words: the context has a sequence of items with the cryptical name `COMP_REC_ENC`. Every item in this sequence has a property `Year`. Keep only those `COMP_REC_ENC` from the sequence that have a value for this property equal to `currYear`

First of all: currYear is an int. Is property Year also an int? If so, the problem is not in the `Where`.

Next, from every item in the remaining sequence of `COMP_REC_ENC` objects, make one new `PoolManager`. Only property `Planning_manager_ID` is filled. The value used to fill `Planning_manager_ID` is `COMP_REC_ENC.Planning_Manager_ID`

Here comes the strange part: I had expected that you would use one of the properties of the current `COMP_REC_ENC` to fill the `Planning_Manager_ID`. I think you will find the problem here.

```
Planning_manager_ID =
```

### How to prevent this kind of problems in future

I have several advices for you:

- Don't mix LINQ method syntax with LINQ query syntax, people coming from SQL world like the query syntax more. People coming from C# world probably prefer method syntax. Method syntax is more flexible, because it is easy to add new LINQ-like methods.
- Try to give your identifiers meaningful names, so every reader will know immediately what they stand for. Use plural nouns for sequences of similar items, use singular nouns for elements from these sequences.
- Don't think that saving on typing by using short identifiers will finish your project earlier. The saved time is nothing compared to the time needed for  others to understand the code when they have to change / test / reuse  it.

If the dbContext class is already used widely, I can understand that it will be hard to convince your project leader to change the dbContext. So you'll have to stick with that.

I haven't got a clue what items are stored in your dbSet `COMP_REC_ENC`, so I'll just give an example to show how much clearer your query will be if you stick to these rules

```
class ComputerPlanning
{
    public int Id {get; set; }                 // primary key
    ...

    public int Year {get; set;}   
    public int PlanningManagerId {get; set;}   // The foreign key to the planning manager
                                               // who created this planning
}

class PlanningDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ComputerPlanning> ComputerPlannings {get; set;}
}
```

Your query according to the guidelines:

**Requirement**: from all computer plannings in the table of ComputerPlannings, keep only those computer plannings that have a Year equal to currentYear. From every remaining ComputerPlanning make one PoolManager with a value of PlanningManagerId equal to the computer planning PlanningManagerId. Remove duplicates and put it all in a list.

```
int currentYear = ...
List<PoolManager> poolManagers = planningContext.ComputerPlannings
    .Where(computerPlanning => computerPlanning.Year == currentYear)
    .Select(computerPlanning => new PoolManager
    {
         PlanningManagerId = computerPlanning.PlanningManagerId,
    })
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Because I stuck to the conventions, it is easy to see for everyone whoe reads the code to see that the code does what the requirement says.

By the way, if you had made an error in `Planning_manager_ID = ...`, your compiler would probably have found the problem already, instead of run time.